# suggestion for a book on algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I don't know if i'm asking in the wrong place, but I'm studying the book Algebraic curves of Fulton, and having some problems understanding the final chapters (6,7 and 8). I've found a good help in the Oswaldo Lezama book of Algebraic geometry for the first chapters, but I can't find something similar for the last chapters. 
If anyone know a book that I could use to help me understand the Fulton better, I'll appreciatte it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following textbooks:

Keith Kendig: Elementary Algebraic Geometry.

Robin Hartshorne: Algebraic Geometry.
(A classic. In my opinion indispensable for any deeper understanding of the subject. The book covers arbitrary dimensions, but two of the five chapters deal with curves and surfaces. These chapters also present a series of examples. The book introduces sheaf theory which is a prerequisite to read the chapters on curves and surfaces.)

Igor Shafarevich: Basic Algebraic Geometry. 
(In my opinion, the book is not "basic". For me it serves as a supplement to Hartshorne's book)

David Mumford: Lectures on Curves on an Algebraic Surface. 
(Aims at experts)